# Hooking C functions

Tags: objective-c, macos, audio, hook, core-audio

I want to hook a C function on Mac OS X. It's `AudioUnitInitialize`, so I can create a callback and save the audio to a file. I got the Mobile Substrate framework with the tutorial from [this page](http://iphonesdkdev.blogspot.de/2012/06/how-to-install-thoes-under-xcode-44.html). Here is my code for hooking that function with `MSHookFunction`.

```
static OSStatus (*AudioUnitInitialize_original)(AudioUnit aInUnit);
OSStatus AudioUnitInitialize_hooked(AudioUnit aInUnit)
{
    NSLog(@"AudioUnitInitialize_hooked -> START");

    OSStatus __return = AudioUnitInitialize_original(aInUnit);

    NSLog(@"%p", aInUnit);
    NSLog(@"%@", aInUnit); // Here the target application crashes.

    NSLog(@"AudioUnitInitialize_hooked -> END");
    return __return;
}

...

MSHookFunction(AudioUnitInitialize, AudioUnitInitialize_hooked, &AudioUnitInitialize_original);
```

What's the problem here? I can log the address of the audio unit but not more? Is there a solution to use the parameters of the function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `AudioUnit` type is not an Objective-C object, it is, in fact, a typedef to a pointer to a struct.  You can't use the `%@` format specifier in `NSLog()` for it.

AudioUnit is a typedef to [AudioComponentInstance](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/AudioUnit/Reference/AudioComponentServicesReference/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007287-1-SW2)

Answer (score 1):

You might like to refer to the [documentation](http://iphonedevwiki.net/index.php/MobileSubstrate) for `MSHookFunction()`

Aside from the rather dubious self-congralutory claim in the first paragraph, lower down the page reads:

*"Conceptually, MSHookFunction() will write instructions that jumps to the replacement function, and allocate some bytes on a custom memory location, which has the original cut-out instructions and a jump to the rest of the hooked function. Since on the iPhoneOS by default a memory page cannot be simultaneously writable and executable, a kernel patch must be applied for MSHookFunction() to work."*

I'm mildly surprised any attempt to do this doesn't result in a memory protection failure.

The orthodox was of interposing C and C++ functions is to provide your own implementation in a library and ensure the linker gets to it before version in the CoreAudioFramework.